# Error starting Wildfly 10.0.0.Final

Tags: java, wildfly-10

I haven't been able to find a specific answer to what could be causing this issue though I am hoping it is something quite simple.

***Issue***.
 I have installed version `10.0.0.Final` from the Wildfly website and extracted into    C:\Program Files\wildfly-10.0.0.Final.

I then navigate to C:\Program Files\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\bin directory via windows command prompt and execute the standalone.bat command.

Wildfly doesn't start and I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate class "org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler" for handler "FILE"
```

If anyone has encountered this error message before, then your guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Ben

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to be a result of either file permissions on the JBoss home directory, lack of space available, or a missing directory.

Relevant posts include:

[Starting WildFly 8.2 under a user with limited permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002607/starting-wildfly-8-2-under-a-user-with-limited-permissions)

Which suggests setting the JBOSS_BASE_DIR property to the root folder of the JBoss installation.

https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/wildfly/issues/24

Suggests this can occur if the root folder does not have enough space allocated for the user (typically running in Unix environments).

[Error in starting Wildfly 8.0 server with JDK 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29513444/error-in-starting-wildfly-8-0-server-with-jdk-1-8)

The logs/boot.log didn't exist. The author manually created the file which then revealed a permission issue on the log file (more likely on the entire Jboss installation folder).

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you for your input and advice. I had noticed the missing directory thread on here so added that in previously, and have now changed my permission settings on the entire folder itself and unfortunately the issue is still occuring.

Comment: Then can you add more information to your question like the full stacktrace, what OS you are using, etc. Also, have you set the JBOSS_BASE_DIR system property?

Comment: Hi, I have been tied up with other commitments (mainly work) :) I am aiming to try this again this weekend, if I am still having issues I will attach the stack trace. OS Wise it's Windows 10 on the machine I am using. Thanks again pczeus.for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused due to the command prompt. As I am using windows 10, I needed to be using Command Prompt (Admin),rather than just the normal cmd hence the permission issues alluded to previously by pczeus.

After using Command Prompt (Admin), I was able to start the server.